# addcontentdb command missed something

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, sql-server-2012

So I have built a new sql 2012 server and SharePoint 2013 server.  I have added the new SharePoint server to the farm and made it the default central admin site.  I have moved all the content databases over to the new SQL server.  I can go to manage content databases from central admin and I select all my sites and it shows the database on the new sql server.

However when I shut down the old SQL server I can't connect to the new central admin site, and adding files to a content database seems to error out on a few of my site collections.

I have Google and Google and cant find anything on what I missed.  Is this common?

Comment: after shut down old SQL server, you getting error on Central admin and few site other site collections, correct?

Answer (score 0):

your missing step 8

> **1**.Prepare the new database server.
>
> **2**.Close all open SharePoint Management Shell windows.
>
> **3**.Stop all services that are related to SharePoint 2013 and Internet Information Services (IIS).
>
> **4**.Detach the databases from the current SQL Server instance.
>
> **5**.Copy or move all files that are associated with the databases (.mdf, .ndf, and .ldf), to the new destination server that runs SQL Server.
>
> **6**.Make sure that all of the SQL Server logins, fixed server roles, fixed database roles, and permissions for the databases are configured
>   correctly on the new destination database server.
>
> **7**.Attach the databases to the new destination server that runs SQL Server.

---

> **8**.Use SQL Server connection aliases to point to the new database server and update all web servers.
>
> If you do not want to use SQL Server connection aliases use one of the
>   following procedures to update the database connections for your
>   SharePoint 2013 farm.
>
> ◦**Scenario 1**: Use this procedure to update the database connections if
>   you use SharePoint Server 2013 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and SQL
>   Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups for high availability or disaster
>   recovery.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx#PS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx#PS)

> ◦**Scenario 2**: Use this procedure if you do not use SharePoint Server
>   2013 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and must use manual steps or if you
>   move the databases from a SharePoint Server 2013 single server
>   installation to a new single server installation.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx#Man](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx#Man)

---

> **9**.Restart all services that you stopped in step 3.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

for aliases connection do:

> 1.This procedure must be performed on all servers in the SharePoint Server 2013 farm that connect to the instance of SQL Server that hosts
>   the databases.
>
> 2.Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a member of the following:
>
> ◦The Administrators group
>
> ◦The db_owner fixed database role
>
> 3.Start the SQL Server Client Network Utility, (cliconfg.exe). This utility is typically located in the C:\Windows\System32 folder on
>   Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (SP1) and Windows Server 2012.
>
> 4.On the General tab, verify that TCP/IP is enabled.
>
> 5.On the Alias tab, click Add. The Add Network Library Configuration dialog box appears.
>
> 6.In the Server alias box, enter the name of the current instance of SQL Server.
>
> 7.In the Network libraries area, click TCP/IP.
>
> 8.In the Connection parameters area, in the Server name box, enter the new server name and instance to associate with the alias, and then
>   click OK. This is the name of the new server that is hosting the
>   SharePoint 2013 databases.
>
> 9.Repeat steps 3 through 8 on all servers in the farm that connect to the new instance of SQL Server.

in your case i presume its an uptodate version for your db and sharepoint so do senario 1 or 2 as they ustalize powershell.